# Event when a page's URL changes without reloading (like history.back())

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm injecting JS using a chrome extension and I need to know the page's URL.

Some modern sites have ways to change the URL without actually reloading the page. From my understanding there's more than one way to do this, so I will appreciate different inputs as my mission is to eventually take care of all cases.

I'm currently looking at 2 random sites I came across that implement this behavior (change the URL on scrolling down) -

https://www.reuters.com/article/us-tesla-results-conferencecall/teslas-musk-calls-wall-street-snub-foolish-but-defends-his-behavior-idUSKBN1I51C8

https://www.wsbtv.com/news/local/henry-county/police-department-fires-officer-after-choking-arrest-video-goes-viral/747195735

Now, I read that some sites a few years ago loaded all their pages on load and then used history.back() to navigate through them.

Things I tried so far on these two sites:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
    // Code
});

window.addEventListener('replaceState', function(e) {
    // Code
});

history.pushState = function() {
    // Code
};

history.replaceState = function() {
    // Code
};
```

Alas, nothing has worked so far.

Comment: See [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: That's a great link, I'm trying some of the suggested methods now. Thanks.

Comment: `history.pushState` isn't an event you assign to, it's a function you call to change the state. The `addEventListeners` should work if you call the functions.